# add-pnpfile doesn't work correctly

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Until now I have the following code that upload a file on SharePoint Online

```
#Connect-PnPOnline https://imncloud.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite -Credentials o365

$file = Get-ChildItem "path\to\file.xxx"
$own = $file.GetAccessControl().owner;
$own=$own.Substring($own.IndexOf("\")+1);
$who = get-pnpuser | Where-Object{$file.LoginName -match "$own"} | select id
Add-PnPFile -Path $file.FullName -folder "path/to/" -Values @{Author=$who.id;Editor=$who.id;Created=$_.CreationTimeUtc; Modified=$_.LastWriteTimeUtc;}
#Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

and it works without any problems. Now, when I try to execute the code I obtain the error that the file or the folder with name https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/path/to" already exists.

Do you know if some changed in the source code?
I also used previously the method

```
ensure-pnpfolder
```

and it, until now, worked like indicated in the help; now, if I use it, I obtain the same error like that before.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does the file already exist?

Comment: No the file doesn't exists.

Comment: You could make sure by doing Get-PnPFile. If it gets nothing then we have another issue

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, but it reasonable that it doesn't exists; the strange is that I used this code Friday without any issue.

Comment: Get-PnPFile retrieves file not found.

Comment: Only to add that I have SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module version 2.18.1709.1